# Bash command to source a file in a different directory?

Tags: bash

I have a collection of bash scripts and I want to put some common shell options and variable declarations into a "setup.sh" script which would get sourced at the beginning of each script.
My directory structure is like:

```
├── includes
│   └── setup.sh
├
└── server_config
    ├── build_server_core.sh
    ├── install_fail2ban.sh
```

Because the scripts may be run from different computers or environments, I can't simply use a hard-coded path to the `setup.sh`

Is there a one-line command to `source` a script in a different directory to the running script?

Comment: How about `source ../includes/setup.sh`?

Comment: @michas that would work, but would require that all scripts are invoked from the same working directory everytime - that would be ok if it was possible to conditionally check if the script was being invoked from the correct directory - and error + exit if not.

Comment: have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/59895

Comment: @michas thanks, Ive looked at that, and it does give the path from the script doing the calling, but that path is longer than the parent directory. it would require removal of the last path segment and then concatenating to the `sourced` path. bit beyond my bash skills unfortunately

Comment: May be you are looking for [`pushd` and `popd`] (http://www.softpanorama.org/Utilities/pushd_popd_and_dirs.shtml)

Comment: I think Michas is on the right track, Im currently searching on how I can remove the last segment from the `DIR` variable then should work!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

First get the directory of the script itself and then use relative paths like that:

```
DIR=$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )
source "$DIR/../includes/setup.sh"
```

For more info about finding the correct directory have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59895

Comment: thanks but it errors out . bash is just seeing the literal string `/home/user/shell-scripts/server_config/build.sh../includes/setup.sh`: No such file or directory

Comment: Are you sure you used the lines exactly as given above? The slash before `..` cannot simply disappear and the `build.sh` part comes out of nowhere... try to run you script with `bash -x` to see what is going on.

Comment: nice one @michas ! I missed out the slash before `..` I dont understand though. is that just a bash feature, that you feed it a long path and then just tack on a `../` and it will start traversing backwards up the directories? thats awesome, Ive just never seen that before!

Comment: It's just the same when you do `cd ..`. On Unix `..` is simply a "normal" directory pointing to the parent directory.

Answer (score 0):

**As a one-liner: double nesting dirname also gets the parent.** (inspired [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8426110/444255))

```
source $( dirname $( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" ) )/_helperlib.sh
```

Answer (score -1):

```
echo "$( echo $(cd ../ && pwd) )/includes/setup.sh"
```

or

```
ParDir="$( echo $(cd ../ && pwd) )/includes/setup.sh"

echo $ParDir
```